# How can you transfer details from high poly to low poly?

Tags: texture-baking, baking, retopology

I sculpted a hand with dyntopo and since it got too dense I tried to retopologize it. I want to transfer the details from the high poly to the low poly mesh. I tried baking the normal map, but the result is not what I was expecting. Is the low poly mesh's geometry bad for this approach ?
Here are a few pictures:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I wanted to have the nails, knuckles, veins etc more visible, but this is my result (material preview mode)

EDIT:

I baked the map again(I used the jbake addon) (both hands were at the same position this time and the result is slightly better)

[image]

Here is my node setup of the low poly mesh.
[image]

And this is the normap map:
[image]

Here is my blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yUh3FVXKVvFmVQt5IQbHaO__fRTtEA-Y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your baked normal mal and the shader node setup for the low-poly hand? And more info on how you baked it? Probably something with the baking went wrong

Comment: I edited a bit the question if you can take a look. I used the jbake addon for baking the maps. If you could take a look at my blend file I would appreciate it

Comment: The greenish part on your normal map are area where the two meshes intersect, you can make the low poly a bit bigger than the high poly by going into edit mode and scale it alont it's normals with alt + S. Then adjust the ray distance in the baking menu (I don't know if there is something similar in jbake) until your baking is OK

Comment: the normal map in the blend file looks better, the artifacts aren't that harsh. It's the little space between the middle finger and the ring finger that causes it. -  If you want to animate it check this out: https://youtu.be/3qj0ZAX61Ho  Your hand looks a bit flat from the side and it made me think of that video ;-)

Comment: thank you, it looks a bit better now. i might have to retouch the hand again before baking it but the results are better now

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to fix. You just took the wrong baked image ;-)

Switch the *Rendering* workspace. There you can see all images in your scene easily. Check the dropdown list (Rendering result) and you'll see that **"hand_lp.001_normal.001"** is the correct baked normal map. In the Image Texture node you have selected "hand_lp.001_normal.**002**", a black one. Just select the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have enough information about how you did your baking, in order to be done properly, the high poly and the low poly should be on the same position and be careful not having a masked object intersecting your low and high poly, otherwise you will have not baked area.

Comment: I edited a bit the question if you can take a look. I used the jbake addon for baking the maps. The hands being at different places was a problem too